# The map does not appear with google map api

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i use google_maps_flutter 0.5.21+6 plugin https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

i did everything in the document and when i run the application there's no error but blank page without map.
added API key in the application manifest

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                   android:value="*************"/>
```

my API settings

[image]

main.dart

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
                      child: GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition:
                  CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.712776, -74.005974), zoom: 12),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

debug

> E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275084@19.2.75 (100700-269183835):22)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275084@19.2.75 (100700-269183835):82)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275084@19.2.75 (100700-269183835):41)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275084@19.2.75 (100700-269183835):54)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275084@19.2.75 (100700-269183835):32)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275084@19.2.75 (100700-269183835):62)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at cv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19275084@19.2.75 (100700-269183835):4)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source:19)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:13)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:18)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source:22)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source:26)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.init(GoogleMapController.java:136)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapBuilder.build(GoogleMapBuilder.java:32)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapFactory.create(GoogleMapFactory.java:51)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:158)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:407)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:302)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:249)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.(VirtualDisplayController.java:92)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.create(VirtualDisplayController.java:52)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:97)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:87)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:51)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views( 6425):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

**update** : i changed the API key place in manifest and it works but still blank with google logo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**solved** 
i added my project to Application restrictions and worked
[image]

*it supposed to work without having to that but i don't know why didn't work.*